# Как распилить монолит на микросервисы?

Tags: c++, микросервисы

На собеседовании по С++ спросили, как можно организовать распил монолита на микросервисы. Больше никаких комментариев к вопросу не дали. Какие уточняющие вопросы мне надо было задать, чтобы понять, что от меня хотят услышать? Кто знает открытые С++ проекты на github/gitlab, где можно посмотреть пример таких распилов?

Comment: Почитайте про unix way.

Comment: возможно необходимо знание каких-то публикаций, кого-то из руководства конторы

Comment: Скорее всего вам надо было выдавать поток buzzwords пока кто-то из интервьюверов не скажет "бинго". ЗЫ unix way тут вообще ни при чем.

Comment: Микросервисы: 1. Маленький и специализированный. 2. Обмениваются через легкие интерфейсы (поток байтов) 3. Объединяются в конвейеры. Unix way.

Comment: Нет стандартного способа.